# Git changes to Dev and branches

Tags: git

I have a branch from ‘Dev’ and I have made changes to it. In the meantime there are changes to ‘Dev’.

I understand that we could rebase or merge the branch with ‘Dev’, but I have pushed some of the changes of my branch to the remote repo.

So if I now rebase my branch on local repo and push that to remote repo, they are not in sync as I have rebased my local branch. So I get an error saying that my local branch is behind my remote branch.

I have several questions on git. Firstly how do I solve this situation. Does rebase work if you already have committed changes to remote repo.

Also I changed some of the files that were changed in ‘Dev’. So My second question is how do I make sure that common changes get overridden by the ‘Dev’ branch changes. Is that merge ?

Sorry if I am confusing ...

Comment: Don't rebase branches which are being shared. This is likely to cause issues.

Comment: Did you `git fetch` before rebasing/pushing?  It's possible that you are just missing some changes from origin.